# How to avoid domain login prompt for an ASP.Net Core 2 WebAPI site - that handles CORS as well as Windows Integrated Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, https, .net-core, cors

I have tried to setup a dotnet core 2.1 WebAPI site that is to be used to return some json data.

The backend must use Windows Authentication (Windows Integrated Security) to authenticate the users as this is to be used on an internal Windows domain.

Since the request will be made from a client-side single page application the solution also must handle CORS. Finally we also will run this in HTTPS only.

So, the client will send a fetch request to the WebAPI that has `credentials=include` set in the request.

To handle CORS I have set up the site to use both anonymous and Windows authentication, since the CORS OPTION HTTP request requires anonymous authentication. One single controller method then has an Authorize attribute though, as that method will require the user-credentials.

The problem is that the first time the browser is opened at the site, the request will prompt the user for domain login credentials, which should not be necessary.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

To Register Class on WebApiConfig  :

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());
```

And this is the class :

```
 public class CorsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    const string Origin = "Origin";
    const string AccessControlRequestMethod = "Access-Control-Request-Method";
    const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
    const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    const string AccessControlAllowMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
    const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(Origin);
        bool isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;
        if (isCorsRequest)
        {
            if (isPreflightRequest)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpResponseMessage>(() =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

                    string accessControlRequestMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
                    }

                    string requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
                    }

                    return response;
                }, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage resp = t.Result;
                    resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
                    return resp;
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to remove all other CORS related handling then I guess? What about authorisation, would I need to do both anonymous and windows for this setup as well? Also, this writes the request origin origin back, right? So, if we want to limit this then we would need to add a config for that.